# Do I need to manually Sanitize Inputs before using them in Eloquent to avoid SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

**Take Note: This is a Native PHP-based Project and NOT Laravel-based.**

I'm currently using Eloquent as a standalone library in my current project (the project was first developed with native PHP by the previous developer and I'm trying to update the system).

I'm trying to filter the items table list based on date that will be passed on via URL.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="date" name="from" required>
    <input type="date" name="to" required>
</form>
```

and now, on the same page:

```
use Includes\Models\Items;

// does this needs some sanitizing?
$from = $_GET["from"] ?? null;
$to = $_GET["to"] ?? null;

$collections = Items::whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])->get();
```

Since the values to be used in the eloquent query are coming from the URL, there is a high chance that it could get modified and risking SQL Injections.

So, I wanna know if Eloquent has a built-in function that guards against this or do I have to manually sanitize the inputs coming from the URL...

Comment: Usually, you should not use `$_GET` in Laravel

Comment: You don't use the `$_` variables in Laravel. It has it's own built-in `Request` class to do all of that for you. Correct syntax would be `Item::where('category', request()->input('category'))->get()` (or `$request->category`, etc.)

Comment: I'm not using laravel. This is a native PHP project

Comment: Also, if you need to sanitize the data depends on what you plan to do with it. SQL injections should be covered by Eloquent without any manual sanitization

Comment: For clarity, removed the `laravel` tag here. You can use Eloquent outside of Laravel, but I have no experience with that. It _should_ be properly sanitized, but do some testing first.

Comment: thank you very much @NicoHaase ! This has just answered my question. This means that (1) option is fine.

Comment: Will do @TimLewis

Comment: You should edit the question to give a clear definition of "sanitise" (which can potentially cover a lot of areas), then it will be much more useful to future readers.

Comment: oh, I will do that then @ADyson , thanks for noting that with me.

Comment: Please share more details. Exchanging "sanitize" with "filter" does not help other to understand your problem better

Comment: Agreed, that doesn't clarify anything unfortunately. Both sanitising and filtering (which _sometimes_ can effectively mean the same thing, depending on the context) can refer to a wide range of activities designed to defend against a wide range of different specific problems. The reader needs to know what you're trying to sanitise _against_ ...you have to understand the nature of the threat in order to be able to suggest a mitigation.

Comment: oh! now I see what you mean! Ok, I'll edit the post and explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not clear, just by reading the question, what you mean by "manually filter beforehand". You also then re-use the word "filter" within the description, by which I think you mean excluding certain rows from the results based on the data (hence the use of `whereBetween()` in the code). So as someone reading this for the first time I'd ask - filter against what? And where? And is that different to the date filtering you refer to in the question? And are you actually experiencing a specific problem in the code currently? It's really no clearer than before, sorry.

Comment: right, I forgot to include the threat.

Comment: Thanks. **now** it makes much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1):

The `whereBetween` and related functions are not part of Eloquent but belong to the Laravel "Query Builder" which is used by Eloquent.

The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#introduction) says:

> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your
> application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean
> strings being passed as bindings.

Answer (score -3):

Edit

I suggest you always sanitize your input data, even though Eloquent makes use of PDO and covers SQL Injection attacks. You are still vulnerable to XSS attacks.

---

Avoid using superglobals in your code. PHP provides an [alternative library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) to retrieve data from requests so that you don't need to use superglobals.

```
$from = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "from") ?? null;
$to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "to") ?? null;
```

For data sanitization, you can also use an external library. I suggest using this one: https://github.com/rodrigojavornik/PHPCleanup.

So, your code would be

```
use PHPCleanup\Sanitize;

$from = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "from") ?? null;
$to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "to") ?? null;

$from = Sanitize::dateTime('Y-m-d H:i:s')->sanitize($from)->getTimestamp();
$to = Sanitize::dateTime('Y-m-d H:i:s')->sanitize($to)->getTimestamp();

$collections = Items::whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question whether manual sanitization is necessary in this case.

Comment: @NineBerry You are right. I updated the response. Thanks

Comment: "You are still vulnerable to XSS attacks" - can you explain that further? Which parts of the given code are vulnerable, and why?

Comment: Prevention against XSS attacks should happen where you put the data from the database into some ouput format. Doing that while putting data into the database is the false place because you cannot know what formats the data will be used in in the future.